# Evenly spacing my buttons

Tags: android, layout, spacing

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.colorchangeapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/RedPositive"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
    android:text="@string/positive_change" 
    android:onClick="redPositive"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/BluePositive"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/RedPositive"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/positive_change" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/GreenPositive"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/BluePositive"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:text="@string/positive_change" />
```

How can you make sure that each button that was created is evenly spaced away from each other. They're aligned on top, but how do i make sure the gap between them is exactly the same?

Comment: Your GreenPositive marginRight is 16dp, RedPositive marginLeft is 15dp.  Other than that, what are you seeing visually that's incorrect?  It appears like it should work to me...

Comment: Also, your GreenPositive doesn't have the `style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"` like the other two.

Answer (score 0):

They way I would do it is to add a LinearLayout and add the buttons to that layout each with a weight of 1 so that they fill the linear layout and space out evenly.

example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```